# Socket.IO chat not working with load balancer AWS (multiple instances)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, websocket, socket.io

I recently integrated basic chat functionality with Socket.IO.

It’s working fine when I am using this with only one instance but while attaching 2 instances to the Application load balancer it just doesn’t work.Message doesn't get received by the user if he is connected on another instance.

Also, I checked for Stickness, & Enabled it but that also doesn't work. What is the recommended way to solve this?

I'm using node.js with express and typescript.

Comment: What have you done to enable your two instances to pass messages to one another in the case where a user on instance A wants to chat with another user on instance B? Also, can you tell us what goes wrong? Are your users disconnecting? Do the messages get lost? Please [edit] your question to give a few more details.